# can't see logcat from android device using Terminal app: Permission Denied!

Tags: android, terminal, logcat

I want to see the exception log that my app throws using logcat. I found that it can be done by using some terminal app. In the terminal I need to enter logcat and it will show me the log. when I try to do it I get: ....... Permission Denied. what can I do to view this log?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need root. If your device is rooted, run "su" first, then logcat.

Comment: Worked for me... what's the full error? Did it prompt to allow root access when you ran su?

Comment: if by su you mean superuser so no